# Making an array and addressing mutliple elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following simple jquery function, but I want to use it on multiple elements with **different classes**. How to I make my code shorter by using an array?

```
$(function() {

  $('.red').attr("href", "images/gallery/redSmall.jpg");
  $('.blue').attr("href", "images/gallery/blueSmall.jpg");
  $('.green').attr("href", "images/gallery/greenSmall.jpg");
  $('.black').attr("href", "images/gallery/blackSmall.jpg");

});
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the array of the classes and than with a for loop applay the href changes to the matching elements:

```
$(function() {
    var classes = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'];

    for(var i=0; i < classes.length; i++)
    {
        $('.'+classes[i]).attr("href", "images/gallery/"+classes[i]+"Small.jpg");
    }
});
```

**You can add as many classes as you want.

Comment: thank you Dan, it works. Really appreciate. Not sure whose code is better between yours and guy mograbi above...

Comment: alright, whos answer will you accept than? (i answered first)

Answer (score 2):

The JQuery way is

```
$(function() {
    $.each(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'],function(index,item){
         $('.'+item).attr("href", "images/gallery/"+item+"Small.jpg");
    });
});
```

However, if you write the HTML better, you can do it even shorter... 
move the "red","blue" ... to another attribute, and add a single class for all. something like

```
<a class="color" data-color="red" href="javascript:void(0)"/>
<a class="color" data-color="blue" href="javascript:void(0)"/>
...
```

and then your JS will be more general and really short

```
$(".color").each(function(item,index){ $(this).attr("href","images/gallery/"+this.attr("data-color")+"Small.jpg"});
```

Comment: thank you, I assume I can replace the image tag with an anchor tag? I must use an anchor tag...Also, how compatible is the 'data-color' property with older/unusual browsers ? How does your original code(the first suggestion) differ from Dan's below? Or is it basically the same?

Comment: might be stupid question, but I assume that in 'data-color', the 'color' part refers to the class, which is color? So if I change the class, I must change data-coor to data-newClassname?

Comment: No - they are not connected. You can change the class to whatever you want